# Tornado's IO Loop doesn't support Windows file descriptors

Tags: python, windows, asynchronous, tornado

I'm trying to get Tornado's IO loop to support Windows file descriptors, but since it uses select, and select does not support Windows file descriptors, i'm in a bit of a problem.

What is the best workaround for using Tornado both as a web server and to read from files asynchronously?

I need to read asynchronously from files because I am reading from process pipes, which use file descriptors for IO.

Comment: "read from files asynchronously?"  are you sure you need this?

Comment: Tornado doesn't use select, it supports epoll and kqueue, both are unavailable on Windows. There's no Windows support at all, though some experimental code can be found in Tornado source on github, see tornado/platform/windows.py.

Comment: I'm using a version which does support Windows, I didn't investigate exactly how official Windows support is there. All I know is that on my Tornado version running Windows, Tornado uses select.
I have to use Windows. If I wouldn't have to use Windows, I would have used Linux.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy well, not from real files. I need to read from process pipes, which have a Windows file descriptor.

Comment: use python library for this, and pass it to tornado.